# My app doesn't load toolbar options

Tags: android

I'm doing a search bar, but I found a problem, because if I put the code at the end of MainActivity it doesn't load options.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

        SearchManager manager = ( SearchManager ) getSystemService ( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });
}}
```

What should I do? Did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure how your code even compiles after putting something after return statement. Doesnt it give error saying unreachable statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is after the return statement, hence, never reached. Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

        SearchManager manager = ( SearchManager ) getSystemService ( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: therefore you have to do something in onQueryTextChange

Comment: well, now that this part of the code works, as Frank said, you either need to perform some filtering yourself within the two callbacks present, or need to make sure your configured your search interface correctly (as you seem to rely on it to perform your search) unfortunately, i don't have enough info regarding what you want to achieve with this search, nor about your current search interface configuration, to understand why it doesn't do what you need it to do.

Comment: probably the best would be to post another question regarding this...but make sure you include your search interface configuration info in your question & your expected result, in order to for us to be able help you find the issue..see this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
```

That is never reached, your return statement is before that. The rest looks fine.

Comment: Thanks but now searchManager gives me error "unreachable statement". what should I do? thanks